# Parent Div has background, want sub div's background to be whats behind the parent Div

Tags: html, css, background, transparency

okay so I have a website, http://psp.pillower.com/ when you click a blue tab (except middle left) a bigger tab pulls out with 2 Divs inside of it, What a want is to have the sub divs show whats behind the green Div especially while its moving, to give it a transparent feel, is there any way to actually do this? Im stumped

Comment: I'm looking for something a bit like globalCompositonOperation but with css instead of canvas

Comment: there's no way of seeing through a solid background. If your dimensions are fixed, you could use a png with a transparent center, or if dimensions are variable, you could add a `svg` to the panel with a clipping mask

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba in your css.

If you want transparent green use this:

```
background: rgba(0, 131, 5, 0.7);
```